# Python urljoin equivalent in AS3

Tags: python, actionscript-3, url

Python has a function urljoin that takes two URLs and concatenates them intelligently. Is there a library that provides a similar function in AS3?

urljoin documentation: http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html

And python example:

```
>>> urljoin('http://www.cwi.nl/doc/Python.html', '../res/jer.png')
'http://www.cwi.nl/res/jer.png'
```

I want to know if there is an implementation of `urljoin`  function, not the whole `urlparse` package

Comment: You could rewrite http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/urlparse.py in AS3 ;)

Comment: Are you looking for the complete python class functionality in AS3 or just the function you described where a base url and a relative url are merged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some raw code doing what you want, so you can skip all of the bloated libraries:

```
var urlJoin:Function = function(base:String, relative:String):String
{
    // See if there is already a protocol on this
    if (relative.indexOf("://") != -1)
        return relative;

    // See if this is protocol-relative
    if (relative.indexOf("//") == 0)
    {
        var protocolIndex:int = base.indexOf("://");
        return base.substr(0, protocolIndex+1) + relative;
    }

    // We need to split the domain and the path for the remaining options
    var protocolIndexEnd:int = base.indexOf("://") + 3;
    if (base.indexOf("/", protocolIndexEnd) == -1) // append slash if passed only http://bla.com
        base += "/";
    var endDomainIndex:int = base.indexOf("/", protocolIndexEnd);
    var domain:String = base.substr(0, endDomainIndex);
    var path:String = base.substr(endDomainIndex);
    if (path.lastIndexOf("/") != path.length-1) // trim off any ending file name
        path = path.substr(0, path.lastIndexOf("/")+1);

    // See if this is site-absolute
    if (relative.indexOf("/") == 0)
    {
        return domain + relative;
    }

    // See if this is document-relative with ../
    while (relative.indexOf("../") == 0)
    {
        relative = relative.substr(3);
        if (path.length > 1)
        {
            var secondToLastSlashIndex:int = path.substr(0, path.length-1).lastIndexOf("/");
            path = path.substr(0, secondToLastSlashIndex+1);
        }
    }   
    // Finally, slap on whatever ending is left
    return domain + path + relative;
};
```

Comment: I upvoted both answers, but I choose yours because of the work you took to code it. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah. If someone already made what you want, you don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Joony @gladoscc Umm... I completely agree.  But the other answer involved including part of `as3corelib` - a notoriously bloated library.  The referenced [URI class](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/blob/master/src/com/adobe/net/URI.as) is 2466 lines.  My complete answer clocks in at 42 lines.

Comment: I only need urljoin function, not a whole library. @NRohler didn't reinvent the wheel, he give me an answer that fit my problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use for example the [URI](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/blob/master/src/com/adobe/net/URI.as) class from [as3corelib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib)

Usage:

```
import com.adobe.net.URI;

// create uri you want to be updated
var newURI:URI=new URI('../res/jer.png')

// update newURI with the full path
newURI.makeAbsoluteURI(new URI('http://www.cwi.nl/doc/Python.html')) 

trace(uri.toString()) // will output http://www.cwi.nl/res/jer.png
```

---

```
// or make an utility function base on it:

function urljoin(url1:string, url2:String):String {
  var uri:URI=new URI(url2)
  uri.makeAbsoluteURI(url1)
  return uri.toString()
}
```